# Is there any way to edit an airflow operator after creation?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a python script that dynamically create task (airflow operator) and DAG basing on a JSON file that maps every option desired. 
The script also dedicated function to create any operator needed.
Sometimes i want to activate some conditional options based on the mapping... for example in a bigqueryOperator sometimes i need a time_partitioning and a destination_table, but i don't want to set on every mapped task.

I've tried to read documentation about BaseOperator, but i can't see any java-like set method.

Function that return the operator for example the bigQuery one

```py
def bqOperator(mappedTask):
    try:
        return BigQueryOperator(
        task_id=mappedTask.get('task_id'),
        sql=mappedTask.get('sql'),  
##destination_dataset_table=project+'.'+dataset+'.'+mappedTask.get('target'),
        write_disposition=mappedTask.get('write_disposition'),
        allow_large_results=mappedTask.get('allow_large_results'),
        ##time_partitioning=mappedTask.get('time_partitioning'),
        use_legacy_sql=mappedTask.get('use_legacy_sql'),
        dag=dag,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        error = 'Error creating BigQueryOperator for task : ' + mappedTask.get('task_id')
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
```

mappedTask inside json file without partitioning

```
        {
            "task_id": "TEST_TASK_ID",
            "sql": "some fancy query",
            "type": "bqOperator",
            "dependencies": [],
            "write_disposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
            "allow_large_results": true,
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "use_legacy_sql": false
        },
```

mappedTask inside json file with partitioning

```
        {
            "task_id": "TEST_TASK_ID_PARTITION",
            "sql": "some fancy query",
            "type": "bqOperator",
            "dependencies": [],
            "write_disposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
            "allow_large_results": true,
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "use_legacy_sql": false,
                        "targetTable": "TARGET_TABLE",
            "time_partitioning": {
                "field": "DATE_TO_PART",
                "type": "DAY"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `bqOperator` as below to handle that case, basically it would pass None when it won't find that field in your json:

```
def bqOperator(mappedTask):
    try:
        return BigQueryOperator(
        task_id=mappedTask.get('task_id'),
        sql=mappedTask.get('sql'),  
        destination_dataset_table="{}.{}.{}".format(project, dataset, mappedTask.get('target')) if mappedTask.get('target', None)  else None,
        write_disposition=mappedTask.get('write_disposition'),
        allow_large_results=mappedTask.get('allow_large_results'),
        time_partitioning=mappedTask.get('time_partitioning', None),
        use_legacy_sql=mappedTask.get('use_legacy_sql'),
        dag=dag,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        error = 'Error creating BigQueryOperator for task : ' + mappedTask.get('task_id')
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it gave me some pythonic syntax i didn't get until now, and probably solved the problem, i will try this out!

Answer (score 0):

There is no private methods or fields in python, so you can directly set and get fields like

```py
op.use_legacy_sql = True
```

Given that I strongly discourage from doing this, as this a real code smell. Instead you could modify you factory class to apply some defaults to your json data. 
Or even better, apply defaults on json itself. Than save and use updated json. This will make things more predictable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it gave me syntax to consider, but i think i will follow kaxil answer because i don't want to get the mapping json too difficult to edit. The final goal is to give to non-developer people an easy tool to create new task in this composer flow. Thank you.